# Values lost in dynamic shiny interface when adding inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app.
You can add input boxes dynamically, add text and then display the values.
If I add values, and then add more input boxes, my previously inputted values are lost.

```
library(shiny)

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Text Inputs"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("addInput", "Add Text Input"),
      actionButton("collectInputs", "Collect Inputs")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("textInputs"),
      textOutput("output")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Track the number of text inputs
  counter <- reactiveVal(1)
  
  # Create dynamic text inputs
  output$textInputs <- renderUI({
    inputList <- lapply(1:counter(), function(i) {
      textInput(inputId = paste0("textInput", i), label = paste("Text Input", i), value = "")
    })
    do.call(tagList, inputList)
  })
  
  # Increment the counter when the "Add Text Input" button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$addInput, {
    counter(counter() + 1)
  })
  
  # Collect inputs when the "Collect Inputs" button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$collectInputs, {
    inputs <- lapply(1:counter(), function(i) {
      inputId <- paste0("textInput", i)
      value <- input[[inputId]]
      return(value)
    })
    
    output$output <- renderText({
      #paste("Collected Inputs: ", toString(inputs))
      paste0(inputs)
    })
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I update the code so that any values already inputted are not lost when new text inputs are added?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `insertUI`:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Text Inputs"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("addInput", "Add Text Input"),
      actionButton("collectInputs", "Collect Inputs")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      div(id = "textInputs"),
      textOutput("output")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Track the number of text inputs
  counter <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  # Increment the counter when the "Add Text Input" button is clicked
  # and insert a text input
  observeEvent(input$addInput, {
    counter(counter() + 1)
    insertUI(
      "#textInputs", where = "beforeEnd",
      textInput(
        inputId = paste0("textInput", counter()), 
        label = paste("Text Input", counter()), 
        value = ""
      )
    )
  })

  ......
```

Note that including an output slot inside an observer, as you do in your app, is bad practice. Rather use `bindEvent`, as I showed you in my answer to your previous question.